# spring boot application is running but its docker image cant connect to maria DB which is installed localy

Tags: spring-boot, docker, mariadb

I have created a docker image for my spring boot application but i am not able to get that to run.
Kindly help me figure this out

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=primary). Connection refused
.
.

2023-04-25T13:04:41.969Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=primary). Connection refused
```

Comment: sorry i was not able to post all logs

Comment: I doubt that your docker container contains MySQL... `localhost` for your app is inside the docker container, it won't access anything outside it.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. In order for folks to help you better, please make sure to share some more details. What does you docker image look like? What's you environment?

Comment: Please show us the configuration you are using: Dockerfile or the name of the docker image you used, env vars, error logs, etc..
From the first site looking at the log you attached, it seems like you are trying to access a database that is on the machine itself, I assume that the machine has another hostname.
Find the host name and then change the configuration in your application to reach to correct db host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `--network="host"` in your docker run command, then 127.0.0.1 in your docker container will point to your docker host. You can get more info and a possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach/24326540#24326540).